# Qt Creater _Debug Constant

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I want to use the _Debug Constant in Qt Creater. But don't get any output. Seems like Qt Creater don't set the _Debug Constant on debugging.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    #ifdef _debug
    qDebug("Test");
    qDebug() << "Test";
    argv* = new char[2]{ "c:\injection.dll", "5" };
    #endif>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Qt defines this by default, but in any case, you can add it yourself to your `.pro` file:

```
debug:DEFINES += _debug
```